# using elements fom parent android layout.xml

Tags: android, checkbox, scope, android-activity, baseadapter

I use a CheckBox in my Activity, which is defined in "main.xml" (cbSetAll).
I also have a BaseAdapter, using "item.xml", for setting customized ListItems in a ListView in "main.xml".

Now i want to check all CheckBoxes, depending on cbSetAll. When I fetch the value of cbSetAll, the app crashes. I do this by

```
boolean bCheckAll = ((CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbSetAll)).isChecked();
```

to set the CheckBoxes in BaseAdapter by

```
((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbSetItem)).setChecked(bCheckAll);
```

If I define

```
boolean bCheckAll = true;
```

everything works. I think, the error is, that the CB is in "main.xml" instead of "item.xml" and so the "view" is scoping in the Nirvana. Can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to create an additional variable in your custom adapter and set this variable from the parent activity. This way you can control the behaviour in the adapter.

You can add this variable to the constructor of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You spotted the problem, you can't access views outside a row from inside. A quick way to do this, would be defining `bCheckAll` as an instance static variable of your `Activity`.-

```
static boolean bCheckAll;
```

In `onCreate` method, add a listener to `cbSetAll CheckBox` so that you can update `bCheckAll` value, and access it from you adapter's `getView` method.